# ObservableCollection projections that is also observable

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-8, collections, observablecollection

I have a observable collection of items in mz ViewModel, say

```
public ObservableCollection<T> Items {get;private set;}
```

that I use in the View with no problems. I want to create a projection of this collection, that is also observable. Something like

```
public IEnumerable<T> ProjectedItems
{
   get 
   {
        Items.OrderByDescending(l=>l.SomeProperty).Take(SomeAmount);
   }
}
```

The idea is that when the Items changes then ProjectedItems will also change (reevaluate the  LINQ expression). Is there a ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For

```
public ObservableCollection<T> Items {get;private set;}
public IEnumerable<T> ProjectedItems  {get;private set;}
```

a solution that seems to work is to subscribe to the `CollectionChanged` event of `ObservableCollection` and reevaluate the LINQ expression:

```
Items.CollectionChanged += (s, e) => ProjectedItems = Items.OrderByDescending(l=>l.SomeProperty).Take(SomeAmount);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't use `IEnumerable<T>` if you are performing binding because deferred execution might have some interesting side effects. Use `IList` or `ICollection` instead.

That said, you should devise your strategy around how often the original collection changes and when it changes, how many items will change. It might be more performant to actually handle extraction of elements yourself if the number of changes is high, otherwise you can simply reconstruct the list whenever the original collection changes.

Answer (score 0):

There's [CollectionViewSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to group, filter and sort items of an ObservableCollection (dynamically if you enable "live" grouping/filtering/sorting), but as far as I know there is no way to use the full range of LINQ operators on `ObservableCollections`.

You could implement your own `INotifyCollectionChanged` that wraps around an existing `ObservableCollection`, applies some methods to it (e.g. `Take` or `OrderBy`), and fires `CollectionChanged` whenever the wrapped collection does.